# Adding commas in numbers of four or more digits

Tags: php, api, youtube, numbers

I have a php script that echoes the view count of a Youtube video using the Youtube API. However, I would like it to add commas when reaching views in the thousands and over.

My code is below:

```
$JSON = file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XQu8TTBmGhA?v=2&alt=json');
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You want [number_format()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
echo number_format($views);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo  number_format($views, 2, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

PHP function **number_format**

**Example:**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, '');
$locale = localeconv();
$decimals = 2;
echo number_format($views, $decimals, $locale['decimal_point'], $locale['thousands_sep']);
```